# How to populate jTable with int type date from SQLite database

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am using the code to populate my jTable in Java (using NetBeans). i am using sqlite database. i am able to fetch all datas except the date data which is stored as long data. When i try to display the data in the jtable i get the below mentioned exceptions

```
public void fetch()
{
 try{
    String sql="select * from customer"; 
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Apps\\SQLite3\\FCC.db");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql); 
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    st.close();
    con.close();        
    }                                        
    catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | NumberFormatException | SQLException e)
  {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}       
}
```

but the date is stored as an integer, and i am getting an Exception Message.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Date
at NewJFrame.jTable1MouseClicked(NewJFrame.java:391)
at NewJFrame.access$400(NewJFrame.java:13)
at NewJFrame$6.mouseClicked(NewJFrame.java:174)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

How do I populate a jTable `date` column with `int` type date from a SQLite database.

Comment: Could you add the data model to your question?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the full exception stacktrace. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Here is the code i am using to populate jTable:                                  
  public void fetch()
    {
     try{
        String sql="select * from customer"; 
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Apps\\SQLite3\\FCC.db");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql); 
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        st.close();
        con.close();        
    }

Comment: _**@Barun**_: I assume your `date` data is stored as `unix_timestamp`. So as an alternative solution, instead of `select * ...` try with `select ..., from_unixtime(intColumnOfDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), ...`. that may help you.